# ScrollMagic.js - How to add content after section swipe?

Tags: javascript, scrollmagic

Using this demo:

http://scrollmagic.io/examples/basic/section_wipes_natural.html

I'm trying to figure out how to add additional content after the last wipe section. Here's a rough idea of what I'm trying to accomplish, hopefully it makes sense.

Code example would be helpful.

[image]

Main issue is the last wipr section stays fixed to the top and doesn't allow the content after it to move to the top, instead behind it.

Answer (score 0):

I've been trying to accomplish the exact same thing. I found an example on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t31294wh/1/) and have modified it so that the last two sections behave normally (scroll up the page without overlapping previous content):

HTML

```
<div style="height:100%;background:#000;text-align:center;"><b>OUTSIDE OF PIN CONTAINER</b></div>
<div id="pinContainer">
     <div class="panel first" style="background:#111;">
        <b>FIRST SLIDE</b>
     </div>
     <div class="panel second" style="background:#333;">
         <b>second slide</b>
     </div>
     <div class="panel third" style="background:#555;">
          <b>third slide</b>
     </div>
     <div class="panel fourth" style="background:#777;">
          <b>fourth slide</b>
     </div>
     <div class="panel fifth" style="background:#999;">
          <b>fifth slide</b>
     </div>
</div>
<div style="background:pink;">
          <b>sixth slide</b>
          <p>
                Aenean lobortis arcu in aliquam rutrum. Aliquam ultrices consequat semper. Cras congue in mauris vel condimentum. Nullam at ipsum euismod, fermentum neque non, interdum lorem. Suspendisse semper, urna sed mattis pellentesque, ipsum urna accumsan enim, nec mattis tellus massa id velit. In quis dolor aliquam, maximus urna sed, vestibulum magna. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Nulla facilisi. Cras sed sollicitudin urna. Etiam mi nibh, ornare in ligula auctor, eleifend hendrerit ipsum. Pellentesque in eros et erat iaculis bibendum. Vestibulum sed ornare sapien. Nunc nec quam ut erat interdum condimentum. Pellentesque mauris nulla, bibendum vel finibus eu, fringilla blandit sapien.
            </p>
            <p>
                Aenean lobortis arcu in aliquam rutrum. Aliquam ultrices consequat semper. Cras congue in mauris vel condimentum. Nullam at ipsum euismod, fermentum neque non, interdum lorem. Suspendisse semper, urna sed mattis pellentesque, ipsum urna accumsan enim, nec mattis tellus massa id velit. In quis dolor aliquam, maximus urna sed, vestibulum magna. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Nulla facilisi. Cras sed sollicitudin urna. Etiam mi nibh, ornare in ligula auctor, eleifend hendrerit ipsum. Pellentesque in eros et erat iaculis bibendum. Vestibulum sed ornare sapien. Nunc nec quam ut erat interdum condimentum. Pellentesque mauris nulla, bibendum vel finibus eu, fringilla blandit sapien.
            </p>
            <p>
                Aenean lobortis arcu in aliquam rutrum. Aliquam ultrices consequat semper. Cras congue in mauris vel condimentum. Nullam at ipsum euismod, fermentum neque non, interdum lorem. Suspendisse semper, urna sed mattis pellentesque, ipsum urna accumsan enim, nec mattis tellus massa id velit. In quis dolor aliquam, maximus urna sed, vestibulum magna. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Nulla facilisi. Cras sed sollicitudin urna. Etiam mi nibh, ornare in ligula auctor, eleifend hendrerit ipsum. Pellentesque in eros et erat iaculis bibendum. Vestibulum sed ornare sapien. Nunc nec quam ut erat interdum condimentum. Pellentesque mauris nulla, bibendum vel finibus eu, fringilla blandit sapien.
            </p>
     </div>

<div style="background:purple;">
          <b>seventh slide</b>
          <p>
                Aenean lobortis arcu in aliquam rutrum. Aliquam ultrices consequat semper. Cras congue in mauris vel condimentum. Nullam at ipsum euismod, fermentum neque non, interdum lorem. Suspendisse semper, urna sed mattis pellentesque, ipsum urna accumsan enim, nec mattis tellus massa id velit. In quis dolor aliquam, maximus urna sed, vestibulum magna. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Nulla facilisi. Cras sed sollicitudin urna. Etiam mi nibh, ornare in ligula auctor, eleifend hendrerit ipsum. Pellentesque in eros et erat iaculis bibendum. Vestibulum sed ornare sapien. Nunc nec quam ut erat interdum condimentum. Pellentesque mauris nulla, bibendum vel finibus eu, fringilla blandit sapien.
            </p>
            <p>
                Aenean lobortis arcu in aliquam rutrum. Aliquam ultrices consequat semper. Cras congue in mauris vel condimentum. Nullam at ipsum euismod, fermentum neque non, interdum lorem. Suspendisse semper, urna sed mattis pellentesque, ipsum urna accumsan enim, nec mattis tellus massa id velit. In quis dolor aliquam, maximus urna sed, vestibulum magna. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Nulla facilisi. Cras sed sollicitudin urna. Etiam mi nibh, ornare in ligula auctor, eleifend hendrerit ipsum. Pellentesque in eros et erat iaculis bibendum. Vestibulum sed ornare sapien. Nunc nec quam ut erat interdum condimentum. Pellentesque mauris nulla, bibendum vel finibus eu, fringilla blandit sapien.
            </p>
            <p>
                Aenean lobortis arcu in aliquam rutrum. Aliquam ultrices consequat semper. Cras congue in mauris vel condimentum. Nullam at ipsum euismod, fermentum neque non, interdum lorem. Suspendisse semper, urna sed mattis pellentesque, ipsum urna accumsan enim, nec mattis tellus massa id velit. In quis dolor aliquam, maximus urna sed, vestibulum magna. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Nulla facilisi. Cras sed sollicitudin urna. Etiam mi nibh, ornare in ligula auctor, eleifend hendrerit ipsum. Pellentesque in eros et erat iaculis bibendum. Vestibulum sed ornare sapien. Nunc nec quam ut erat interdum condimentum. Pellentesque mauris nulla, bibendum vel finibus eu, fringilla blandit sapien.
            </p>
     </div>
```

JS

```
$(function () { // wait for document ready
     // init
     var controller = new ScrollMagic.Controller();
     // define movement of panels
     var wipeAnimation = new TimelineMax()
         .fromTo("div.panel.second", 1, {y: "100%"}, {y: "0%", ease: Linear.easeNone})  // in from left
         .fromTo("div.panel.third",    1, {y:  "100%"}, {y: "0%", ease: Linear.easeNone})  // in from right
         .fromTo("div.panel.fourth", 1, {y: "100%"}, {y: "0%", ease: Linear.easeNone}) // in from top
         .fromTo("div.panel.fifth", 1, {y: "100%"}, {y: "0%", ease: Linear.easeNone}); // in from bottom
         // create scene to pin and link animation
     new ScrollMagic.Scene({
         triggerElement: "#pinContainer",
         triggerHook: "onLeave",
         duration: "300%"
     })
     .setPin("#pinContainer")
     .setTween(wipeAnimation)
     .addTo(controller);
});
```

CSS

```
body {
  font-family: "Source Sans Pro", Arial, sans-serif;
  background-color: #c7e1ff;
  font-size: 13px;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  color:#fff;
}
body, html {
  height: 100%
}
#pinContainer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.panel {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  text-align:center;
}
b {
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  position:relative;
  font-size:30px;
}
```